# YET ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration

Tags: maven, log4j2, tomcat9

I'm setting up a new project with Spring MVC and I can't configure Log4j2,
I'm getting the same error as many asked for help.

*ERROR StatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found. Using default configuration...*

Tools and libs:

- Eclipse Photon
- Spring MVC 5.1.6
- Slf4j 1.7.26
- Log4j2 2.11.2
- Maven (from Eclipse)

#### pom.xml

```xml
...
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.26</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jcl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
...
```

#### Configuration files src location

```
/src/com/mypackage/myproject/resorces/
where I tried to put a log4j2-test.xml file and/or a log4j2.properties, none of them worked
```

#### Browsing Tomcat deployment dir:

.../org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MonitorManagement/WEB-INF/classes/com/mypackage/myproject/resources

I **can** find both the resources.

How log4j2 is unable to locate them even if resources are actually deployed?

**EDIT**: It works putting resources directly under src folder, could this be a good way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4j looks in the root folder in the classpath.

In your IDE you can put the `log4j2.xml` file under `/src` and (probably) under `/resources`.

Comment: I've always been used to put this kind of resources on "com.example.myproject.resources", was that a bad practice?

Comment: Log4j 2 looks in the the classpath root. If you put the log4j2.xml configuration in another directory/package, Log4j won’t be able to find it...